# Python Selenium, page_source not holding full html page contents even after page fully loaded

Tags: python, html, selenium

#### Question

How can I make sure `page_source` holds the whole html content of this web page when fully loaded?

#### Description of the problem

I am trying to download a few genes and automate a selenium process. I have a number of genes where on the gene's summary page I would like to download a **csv** summary.

*Here is sample link of a gene summary page with the download and csv buttons highlighted in red.*
http://research-pub.gene.com/BrainMyeloidLandscape/BrainMyeloidLandscape2/#Human-gene/Human-gene/100034743/geneReport.html

[image: Button I want to click on (csv)]

When I load the web page and even wait until it is fully downloaded, `driver.page_source` does not contain the button class within its contents even though the page is fully loaded and I can inspect the element and find it.

*The download button class.*

```
<i class="fa fa-download fa-fw"></i>
```

*The actual csv button I want to find and simulate a click.*

```
<a href="#" class="ep-download" data-download-csv="">.csv</a>
```

I know some answers said to implement `WebDriverWait`, but even when it is implemented the `page_source` does not contain the classes I am looking for. How can I make sure `page_source` holds the whole html content of this web page?

Here is my sample code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get('http://research-pub.gene.com/BrainMyeloidLandscape/BrainMyeloidLandscape2/#Human-gene/Human-gene/23550/geneReport.html')
print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)

#just to see what is initially saved in page_source
print(driver.page_source)


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'fa fa-download fa-fw')))

#wanted to see what is saved after, and the whole page doesn't show
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Do you mind trying `time.sleep(10)`  for testing purpose ?

Comment: Hi, even when  I use ```time.sleep(10)``` instead of  ```WebDriverWait``` the whole page doesn't load

Comment: The website won't load completely in a regular browser. It seems this website uses cookies to find out how did you reach the page and won't load completely. How did you find this link, by the main page or by google search?

Comment: We have this page in our research centre. It is a bookmark on my end.